# How to verify a signature via PHP that was created on the OpenSSL command line?

Tags: php, cryptography, openssl

It seems that PHP's `openssl_sign` and `openssl_verify` functions perform hashing of the data before signing, due to size restrictions, so I've tried emulating this on the command line.

Signing via openssl:

```
echo "foo" | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl rsautl -inkey priv.pem -sign > sig.bin
```

then verifying via PHP

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_public('pub.pem');
$ver = openssl_verify( "foo\n", file_get_contents('sig.bin'), $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1 );
// $ver always 0
```

I've tried numerous combinations, binary and hex forms of the hash, with and without the trailing newline, and even hashing before passing into php function

Answer (score 1):

My findings are that PHP's sign and verify are not interoperable with openssl's rsautl `-sign` and `-verify` options. PHP seems to add some meta data, (an extra 15 bytes) although I don't know what it means.

My solution:
I am using encrypt and decrypt functions directly and handling the hashing myself.

This way, the command line `-verify` option is analogous to "decrypt with public key".
By the same token `-sign` is analogous to "encrypt with public key"

In fact, this way you can define your own signature format, for example including a date along with the hash

Comment: the [pkeyutl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkeyutl.html#) command can do the hashing and signing in one step.

Comment: Thanks, although my installation of openssl (Mac) doesn't have this utility